# How to add a static frame with respect to odom at the place of another frame?

Tags: ros, octomap, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to add a fixed placed at the same location of the camera_frame. The camera is attached to the robot and so is the camera_frame. However the frame moves along with the robot. I can add a static frame camera_frame_fixed at the location using a ROS node. The node would listen to the transform between the odom and camera _frame once, store the values, and then publish a static transform between odom and the camera_frame_fixed using these values. Is there another way to do this without creating a ros node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260846/how-to-add-a-static-frame-with-respect-to-odom-at-the-place-of-another-frame?/) by [hc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27378/hc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2017-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you might know, you can always quickly publish tf transforms via the static transform publisher:

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0.2 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 base_link camera_frame 1000
```

That being said, your application sounds rather specialized, so I don't think you'll get around writing a small Python node for achieving what you want.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27378/hc/) on 2017-05-02**:
Writing the node is easy. As I state in the sub question, that method exists. And I have done that before.
Is there some other way to add it? The static transform requires values to be known. And they must somehow be read once, stored and substituted.